# Delete junk text from all the post using my sql command

Tags: posts, mysql, sql

Because of an autoblog plugin, my site has got junk text in every post!

The text format is as below ..

`funny-pictures/funny-pictures-of-the-day-30-pics/attachment/funny-pictures-41-2/" rel="attachment wp-att-3846">`

Almost every post has the above text with the same format but different text.

Is here any SQL command with which I can delete all this junk text from all my post?

More examples:

`funny-pictures/funny-pictures-of-the-day-30-pics/attachment/funny-pictures-42-4/" rel="attachment wp-att-3847">`

`funny-pictures/funny-pictures-of-the-day-30-pics/attachment/funny-pictures-46-3/" rel="attachment wp-att-3848">`

`funny-pictures/funny-pictures-of-the-day-30-pics/attachment/funny-pictures-48-2/" rel="attachment wp-att-3849">`

Comment: As this is an SQL-specific question you might want to give it a try over at [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)...

Comment: @tf As this requires knowledge about WordPress’ database schema, it is on topic **here**.

Comment: That looks like a broken `src` or `a` tag. Is that really all that appears in your post body?